# How to redirect to another site using POST from web api?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api that redirects to another site as below. Is it possible to redirect to another site using POST? Response.Redirect seems to be doing only GET. What are the alternatives to achieve POST? Thank you!

```
[HttpGet]
public void Load(string type)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

//How to do POST here instead of GET ?
    response.Redirect("http://localhost:58372/TestController?type=test");
}


 public class TestController : Controller
 {
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(string type)
    {
        return View();
    }
 }
```

Comment: The request must be sent from the client side, so why not just send the address to the client and make a post request from there?

Comment: an API does not redirect anything. an API takes a request and provides data as response. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do POST with server side redirects. 
So one option is do a post request with your client app.

Or else you can use Fluentx.Mvc. You can get it from Nuget. 
There are online resources you can read.

Answer (score -1):

This is asp classic code, not sure if this will help or if this is something you are looking for:

```
domain = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
if instr(1,domain,"yahoo") > 0 or instr(1,domain,"google") > 0  or instr    (1,domain,"msn") > 0 or instr(1,domain,"bing") > 0 then
    response.redirect "https://DomainName.com"
 end if
```